# How to calculate sum of digit of a power

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

Find the sum of the digits of:

$$\left\lfloor\frac{k^{h+1}-1}{h-1}\right\rfloor$$

I need to calculate sum of digits in answer. Note as $k$ and $h$ can be a very big value, answer is getting overflow.

What is a better way to calculate this?

Comment: Could you re-write "answer"? There seems to be an extra parenthesis.

Comment: The answer is *syntax error* at this stage ... Could you match brackets and explain you notation in a little more detail?

Comment: @NotNotLogical Done.

Comment: @String corrected the mistake.

Comment: @Amzoti Lets take 100000 as h and k as 100.

Comment: Do you mean the sum of the digits of $\frac{k^{h+1}-1}{h-1}$? And why should this yield an integer in the first place?

Comment: @String Updated :(